# Variable used as parameter can't change its value? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

One of my tasks in VB.NET was to create a program in vb.net that takes in 15 inputted test scores from the user, calculates the average, and then returns the corresponding letter grade. The code is below.

```
Module Module1
    Public Test1 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test2 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test3 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test4 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test5 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test6 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test7 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test8 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test9 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test10 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test11 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test12 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test13 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test14 As Decimal = 0
    Public Test15 As Decimal = 0
    Public counter As Integer = 1
    Public letterGrade As Char
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("This program will take 15 inputted test scores, 
        and then it will return an average and letter grade")
        question(Test1)
        question(Test2)
        question(Test3)
        question(Test4)
        question(Test5)
        question(Test6)
        question(Test7)
        question(Test8)
        question(Test9)
        question(Test10)
        question(Test11)
        question(Test12)
        question(Test13)
        question(Test14)
        question(Test15)
        Dim av As Decimal
        av = (Test1 + Test2 + Test3 + Test4 + Test5 + Test6 + Test7 + Test8 
        + Test9 + Test10 + Test11 + Test12 + Test13 + Test14 + Test15) / 15
        If av >= 90 Then
            letterGrade = "A"
        ElseIf 80 <= av < 90 Then
            letterGrade = "B"
        ElseIf 70 <= av < 80 Then
            letterGrade = "C"
        ElseIf 60 <= av < 70 Then
            letterGrade = "D"
        Else
            letterGrade = "F"
        End If
        MsgBox("You average is" + Str(av) + "%. You got a " + letterGrade + 
        "!")
    End Sub

    Sub question(ByVal score2 As Decimal)
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter test score number" + Str(counter))
        input(score2)
        counter += 1
    End Sub

    Sub input(ByVal score As Decimal)
        Try
            score = Console.ReadLine()
            If score < 0 Then
                Throw New Exception()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid input (number was too 
            large, was a negative, or was not a number)")
            question(score)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

The program first creates 15 variables. Then in the Main program, it runs the question function (which has a parameter), which asks the user to input a score. Lastly, it runs the input function (which has a parameter), which records the users input and stores it in the parameter. If an exception is caught, the input goes back to the question function and asks the same question again. It does this until the user inputs a valid input then moves on to the next test score. After getting 15 inputs, it averages them all and finds the letter grade. I put the variables I created originally as the parameters, so they are supposed to change their value to whatever the user inputs. Hover, when I run the program, it returns an average of 0 and a letter grade of B no matter what numbers I input. I told the program to print the variables after they were supposed to change, and it printed 0 for all of them, which was the initial value I set for them. Why does this happen? Can variables be used as a parameter and change their value to a user input in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable used in a function and keep it's value, but in order to do that you must pass with Reference.

In your code you are using 'Byval', just change it to ByRef.

```
Sub question(ByRef score2 As Decimal)

Sub input(ByRef score As Decimal)
```

Parameters used with 'ByVal' basically have it's values copied into another variable and given to the function do to whatever needs to be done inside it.

When you set it to be passes as Ref (ByRef) you are acctually passing a pointer to the variable itself and access are made directly to it, and not to a copy.

Take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference)

Comment: Thank you very much! The program works and I have understood what you are telling me! Thank you again!